# .NET Regular expression for querystring value

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to strip out any "&id=SomeValue" from a Url.PathAndQuery.  Where SomeValue could be an int or a string.  And it may or may not be followed by another ampersand.

So it could be

```
somepage.aspx?cat=22&id=SomeId&param2=4
```

or

```
somepage.aspx?cat=tect&id=450
```

I want to be left with

```
somepage.aspx?cat=22&param2=4
```

or

```
somepage.aspx?cat=tect
```

Comment: Uhhh, yeah...But I wanted the C# syntax for the pattern. That includes the escaping required BECAUSE it is being used in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just going off the top of my head...

```
string url = "somepage.aspx?cat=22&id=SomeId&param2=4";
Regex regex = new Regex("([\?\&])id=[^\?\&]+");
url = regex.replace(url, "\1");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("url = " + url);
```

**Update 2010-03-05 11:12 PM PST**

I've been shamed by a comment into actually testing my code.  What are you, my QA department?  Here's a working example using MSTest.

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\?\&])id=[^\&]+[\&]?");

    [TestMethod]
    public void RegexReplacesParameterInMiddle()
    {
        string url = "somepage.aspx?cat=22&id=SomeId&param2=4";
        url = regex.Replace(url, "$1");
        Assert.AreEqual("somepage.aspx?cat=22&param2=4",url);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RegexReplacesParameterInFront()
    {
        string url = "somepage.aspx?id=SomeId&cat=22&param2=4";
        url = regex.Replace(url, "$1");
        Assert.AreEqual("somepage.aspx?cat=22&param2=4", url);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RegexReplacesParameterAtEnd()
    {
        string url = "somepage.aspx?cat=22&param2=4&id=SomeId";
        url = regex.Replace(url, "$1");
        Assert.AreEqual("somepage.aspx?cat=22&param2=4&", url);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void RegexReplacesSoleParameter()
    {
        string url = "somepage.aspx?id=SomeId";
        url = regex.Replace(url, "$1");
        Assert.AreEqual("somepage.aspx?", url);
    }

    public void RegexIgnoresMissingParameter()
    {
        string url = "somepage.aspx?foo=bar&blet=monkey";
        url = regex.Replace(url, "$1");
        Assert.AreEqual("somepage.aspx?foo=bar&blet=monkey", url);
    }
```

The regex, interpreted, says:

```
Look for a "?" or an "&" character (and store it as a backreference)
followed by "id="
followed by one or more non-"&" characters.
optionally followed by another "&"
```

Then replace that expression with the backreference, so you don't lose your initial ?/&.

**note** -- as you can see from the tests, this emits a trailing ? or & when the replaced parameter is the only one or the last one, respectively.  You could use string methods to get rid of that, though if somebody knows how to keep them out of the result using only regular expressions it would be excellent to see.

Comment: This code does not compile, nor does it produce the correct output if the compilation errors are fixed. +1 because there are good ideas in the pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

If bad things could happen (e.g., security-wise) if an "id=" parameter were missed by the regular expression, then you also need to worry that the query string might contain a hexadecimal urlencoded equivalent, which the regular expression will not recognize. For example, "id" is "%69%64". Also consider the effects of different capitalizations of "id" on your program. My opinion in this situtation is that you read the RFCs and build a complete class that can do transformations in both directions from a set of name-value pairs to a query strings. `System.Uri` will not do this.  if you are running inside an ASP.NET application, you might investigate if `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would first parse the Querystring to Strongly typed values, then I would check using Regex if I needed to.

> [C# ASP.NET QueryString parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574868/c-asp-net-querystring-parser)