# Get parameter from url string

Tags: asp.net

If I have a URL but as a string e.g. `www.example.com?q=1234&h=4567` how can I pick out e.g. "q"

I'm picking the url up from a database so I can't use `request.querystring("q")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ASP.NET QueryString parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574868/c-sharp-asp-net-querystring-parser)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**HttpUtility.ParseQueryString**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx):

```
string url = new Uri("http://www.example.com?q=1234&h=4567").Query;
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url);
foreach (string key in nvc.AllKeys)
{
     // ...
}
```

(note that i've added the "http" to the url, otherwise you could not create an `Uri`)

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri("http://www.example.com?q=1234&h=4567").Query).Get("q")
```