# Capturing from the link

Tags: asp.net

```
    http://localhost:606/Default.aspx?TerminalNo=008
```

How can I copy the Terminal number=008 of the above path in to an x variable in the program.

Comment: Where you want to read the `TerminalNo`? In _Default_ page load or somewhere else.

Comment: use Request.QueryString

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ASP.NET QueryString parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574868/c-sharp-asp-net-querystring-parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string x = Request.QueryString["TerminalNo"];
        int y = convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TerminalNo"]);
 }
```